# React - How to change code written in the old way when using a new approach?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

I was looking for steps on the internet to refactor previous applications for a new approach, but I did not find a satisfactory answer...

**I know the previous approach for creating applications in *ReactJS* which uses the** `Component` **and** `render()` **function for example, but I can see that it is currently different because:**

```
npx create-react-app app-name
```

**is now generating a different template.**

For example, previously it was imported:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

and now only:

```
import React from 'react';
```

**I am asking for tips or simple advice on what I should change so that the old code works without importing the** `Component`.

**Has the method of using functions for communication via *AJAX*** (e.g. `loadPerson`) **changed as well?**

For example here is some not working example of `./src/PersonDetail.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DetailList } from './DetailList';
import { loadPerson } from './requests';

export class PersonDetail {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {person: null};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const {personId} = this.props.match.params;
    const person = await loadPerson(personId);
    this.setState({person});
  }

  render() {
    const {person} = this.state;
    if (!person) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title">{person.name}</h1>
        <div className="box">{person.description}</div>
        <h5 className="title is-5">Details at {person.name}</h5>
        <DetailList details={person.details} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the [introduction of *hooks*](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) some core concepts begin to change. Before *React 16.8* we used to have a rule of thumb to decide rather a component should be based on `class` or `function`:

> If the component should hold state then it should be class based. If it doesn't have state (stateless) then it could be a functional component

This used to be true cause there wasn't a way to implement stateful logic inside functional components. Now *hooks* allow you to implement `state` in functional components.

The boilerplate generated by `create-react-app` doesn't import `Component` from `react` anymore cause only class based components need to `extends` from `Component` and `App` is now a functional component.

**Nothing changed really it's just another way to write your components.**

Just import like it used to be:

```
export class PersonDetail extends React.Component
```

or give *hooks* a chance and turn your component into a *functional component*:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DetailList } from './DetailList';
import { loadPerson } from './requests';

const PersonDetail  = ({ personID }) => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
      const person = await loadPerson(personId)
      setPerson(person)
  }, [personID])

  return !person ? null : (
    <div>
      <h1 className="title">{person.name}</h1>
      <div className="box">{person.description}</div>
      <h5 className="title is-5">Details at {person.name}</h5>
      <DetailList details={person.details} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think `hooks` came in version 16.8. Cannot propose an edit as it is shorter that 6 chars to fix it :)

Answer (score 3):

To add to other comments...

You can have *class-based components* side by side to *functional components*, there is no inherent need to re-write any old *class-based components* you have written.

[Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

> ### No Breaking Changes
>
> Before we continue, note that Hooks are:
>
> - **Completely opt-in.** You can try Hooks in a few components without rewriting any existing code. But you don’t have to learn or use Hooks right now if you don’t want to.
> - **100% backwards-compatible.** Hooks don’t contain any breaking changes.
> - **Available now.** Hooks are now available with the release of v16.8.0.

Answer (score 2):

With this import,

```
import React from 'react';
```

You can extend `Component` without importing like,

```
export class PersonDetail extends React.Component{ ...}
```

---

**Update**

[Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) are newly added in **React 16.8** and it is not recommended that we should change our exsiting code with `Hooks`. We can still have our exsiting class-based approach which extends `Component` or `React.Component`.

`Hooks` gives us the capability of maintaining `state` of the component as well as it gives a space to write `React lifecycle methods`.

For example, `state` in class-based component

```
state = {
   stateVariable : "stateValue" 
}
```

In new approach, it is equivalent to

```
const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState("stateValue")
```

And for the lifecycle methods we have `useEffect`.

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(stateVariable);
});
```

of-course we need to import `useState` and `useEffect` from `react` package,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
```

Finally, the class-based component

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component{

   state={
       stateVariable : "stateValue" 
   }

   componentDidMount(){
       console.log(this.state.stateVariable)
   }   

   render(){
      return(
          <div> {this.state.stateVariable} </div>
      )
   }
}
```

can be converted to functional component like,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const MyComponent = (props) => {

 const [stateVariable, setStateVariable] = useState("stateValue")

 useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(stateVariable)
 })

  return(
      <div> {stateVariable} </div>
  )
}
```

**Note:** We don't have access to `this` in functional component because we don't have class anymore.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think he didn't ask how he can fix his class component, but how he could move to functional components.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the "new approach" you are talking about are React Hooks.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DetailList } from "./DetailList";
import { loadPerson } from "./requests";

const PersonDetail = props => {
    const [person, setPerson] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { personId } = props.match.params;
            setPerson(await loadPerson(personId));
        })();
    }, []);

    if (!person) {
        return null;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="title">{person.name}</h1>
            <div className="box">{person.description}</div>
            <h5 className="title is-5">Details at {person.name}</h5>
            <DetailList details={person.details} />
        </div>
    );
};

export { PersonDetail };
```

Answer (score 2):

The change you noticed is that create-react-app now creates functional components. This means your components are no longer classes but just functions.

You can still import `Component` and export a class that extends Component.

You don't need to write your class as a function but to write the example class as a functional component you can do the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DetailList } from './DetailList';
import { loadPerson } from './requests';

export default props => {
  const { personId } = props.match.params;
  const [person, setPerson] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    loadPerson(personId).then(person => setPerson(person));
  }, [personId]);
  if (!person) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="title">{person.name}</h1>
      <div className="box">{person.description}</div>
      <h5 className="title is-5">
        Details at {person.name}
      </h5>
      <DetailList details={person.details} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can read more about react hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use class components, you have to make them extend `React.Component`.

There is another way to create components now, which is the functional way. Meaning that a component can be a simple JavaScript function returning an element (usually, some JSX). In this case, you don't need to import `React.Component` anymore.

Class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

class PersonDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Functional component (this is the way React and the community is now pushing for):

```
import React from "react"

const PersonDetail = () => {
  return (<Your JSX code>)
}
```